# var is not identified in JavaScript (Syntax error)

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I have been trying to find ways to solve the problem. Firebug said syntax error, and JSHint is saying **"Expected an identifier and instead saw 'var'."** on line 4 (*var test1 = [*) Could you tell me why this error is taking place? Thanks!

```
function name() {
    if (
    var test1 = ['selected': -1, 'AF': 0.02];
    var selectedTest1 = $('#test1').val();
    var rate = rates(selectedTest1);
    var callMinutes = document.calc.minutes.val();
    document.calc.pay.value = selectedTest1 * callMinutes;)
    else(
    (document.calc.test1.value == null) || (document.calc.minutes.value == null || document.calc.minutes.value.length == 0)) {
        document.calc.pay.value = "Incomplete data";
    }
};
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense.  What do you think it means?

Comment: Did you read the code before posting? You're defining vars inside the `if` statement..

Comment: Why the downvotes? Despite OP being a newbie, the question is very valid.

Comment: I should mention that I'm learning, thanks for pointing out something else that I need to study. :)

Comment: The question does not show research effort? Checked.
The question is not useful? (Meaning, to someone else than OP) Checked.
The question is clear? Well it is clear I give you that I guess. Note that downvotes don't mean a question is invalid.

Comment: @Tiridako despite being a valid question, you should definitely read some tutorials and learn javascript. Look at some tutorial like http://javascript.info and you will see that your problem is very basic.

Comment: Upvoted question to compensate - agree with @FlorianMargaine.  Go back to javascript 101 (or software 101).  But keep asking questions.  And be sure to accept the most helpful answer so people will still want to answer your qeustions.

Comment: The point for my comment above: OP writes the `else (condition) {do stuff}` perfectly fine, seems to me that there was a lack of revising your code before posting. I'd suggest writing your code with a syntax highlighter, they're really helpful.

Comment: The [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) is really nice for resources... [Here is a bookmarked list of tut videos worth watching](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/conversation/learn-javascript-videos) and for the love of pete stay away from w3schools and instead use MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) or MSDN (Microsoft Developer Network) although MDN usually has been good enough for me.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: Maybe because Firebug and jsHint together described the specific problem. Debugging tools are of little use if you ignore what they're telling you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not valid to put a `var` statement inside an `if` condition. That aside, your code can be boiled down to:

```
if( define some variables here)
else (something that makes no sense) {
    show an error
}
```

The code is completely invalid.

Comment: Thanks! I learned something new.

Comment: @Tiridako I'd love to know what your intention was with that code

Answer (score 2):

```
if (var x = 0)
```

you can't define a var inside an if condition

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a condition in your if statement. It should be something like this:

```
if( /* some condition goes here */ ){
    var test1 = [
             'selected': -1,
             'AF': 0.02 
            ];
    var selectedTest1 = $('#test1').val();
    var rate = rates(selectedTest1);
    var callMinutes  = document.calc.minutes.val();
    document.calc.pay.value = selectedTest1 *  callMinutes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the problems with your if statements (you don't have a condition.. if you did it would look like:

```
if(condition){
   var...
else {
  (document...
```

On top of that, you're using brackets to define an object; an object literal in javascript has to be in braces:

```
var test1 = { 'selected': -1, 'AF': 0.02 };
```

Comment: Braces are the {}, brackets are the [].

Comment: Question, somewhere else on stackoverflow, it states that brackets [] are for creating an Array for a var, am I wrong in this case?

Comment: what you're making is an object not an array; I'm guessing you're coming from PHP? In javascript PHP's associative array is an object-- Arrays in javascript can only be indexed by number, so they don't have keys.

Answer (score 0):

Should test1 be an object or an array? You're mixing the two syntaxes. If it's an object, use curly braces { } instead of square brackets [ ]:

```
var test1 = {
    'selected': -1,
    'AF': 0.02 
};
```